# MediaController.show() doesn't work?

Tags: android, media-player

Every time I used the **MediaController.show(int timeout)**, it doesn't work? Does anyone know why? eg:

```
mMediaController.show(30000);
```

Comment: @Reno also `hide()` doesn't work

Comment: To quote the documentation: "Functions like `show()` and `hide()` have no effect when MediaController is created in an xml layout."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you defining MediaController in xml? If yes then please see the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MediaController.html#show) which says

> Functions like show() and hide() have no effect when MediaController
>   is created in an xml layout.

Comment: I created the videoView in xml, but MediaController in java. does it matter?

Comment: looking for an answer here as well